# What is the point of rethrowing an exception in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception

I see a code that goes like this:

```
try {
  // code
  // ...
} catch (e) {
  throw(e);
}
```

That's it. There's nothing else in that `catch` block.

Why would I want to do that? Isn't that exactly the same as letting the exception pass through?

Comment: Possibly an artifact of debugging, there used to be some console.logs or debugger in there. Otherwise, no sense at all.

Comment: As @georg said, probably to set a breakpoint there and someone forgot to remove that.

Comment: Btw, This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing it does is alter the stack trace.

```
function hurl() {
    throw 'chunder';
}
```

This exception will appear to originate from within `hurl`:

```
hurl();
```

This exception will appear to originate from `(anonymous)` (or whatever scope it'll be):

```
try {
    hurl();
} catch (e) {
    throw e;
}
```

So it might be useful if you want to obscure the origins of an exception for whatever reason (can't think of why you might want to, but there you are). Other than that, there's no point to it.

Comment: This is misleading. `throw` does not alter the stack of real `Error` instances (`new Error()`). The example given only "works" because: strings are not real errors and Dev Tools have their own error-catching mechanism that fakes stack traces for non-errors. — Since you should never throw non-errors, we shouldn't suggest that "re-throwing can obscure the origin of an exception", also because a string is not an exception to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

There is no use of throw in catch block. the below code will print err.

```
try { 
        if(x == "")  throw "empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
        if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
        if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
    }
    catch(err) {
         console.log("Input is " + err);
    }
```

if you put throw in catch block it will not print the error like below

```
try { 
        if(x == "")  throw "empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
        if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
        if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw err;
        console.log("Input is " + err);
    }
```

Comment: I think the OP knows that.

Comment: There are very well uses to `throw` in a `catch` block. The question is what the point is if that's the *only* statement in the `catch` block.